Difficult because non-convex, or some other reason?
In my github project, I have come up with a very simple function that seems to cause problems for all the optimizers I have thrown it at, and I am wondering why.  There is an obvious downhill direction at all points, and a single global minimum.  I call it the "treacle function", because it seems to bog optimizers down in a pretty consistent manner.
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{|x_i|}$$
From a non-expert inspection I would say it is definitely non-convex, in "bulk" as well as along the axes, but is that really what makes it hard to solve, or is that a red herring?  Here is what it looks like in 2D:

Incidentally, I actually code it as:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sqrt{|x_i - (i + 1)|}$$
to help defeat biased optimization algorithms (related question here), but I wanted to make the structure crystal clear at the outset!
My code is available here.
[EDIT]  I am beginning to think there is something inherently "difficult" with fractional powers in general.  Perhaps the mechanism of this difficulty is to do with the slope (and therefore the rapid variation) of $f$ at the solution point. This has (IMO) more to do with "gluing" non-convex functions together, but is certainly related to non-convexity.

Is there a specific behavior you mean by "bog optimizers down"? What do the solvers do? get stuck in the branches?

How do gradient-free optimization routines fare? It is no surprise that derivative-based routines will perform poorly as your function is not differentiable at the minimum.

The function is nowhere convex, and it's not differentiable along the axes as well as at the minimum. No wonder it's hard to find a minimum.

You could try to disambiguate whether the problem is lack of smoothness or lack of convexity by smoothing the function a bit around 0. So instead use $f(x) = \sum_i\sqrt{|x_i - (i + 1)| + \epsilon}$. For small $\epsilon$, this will still be smooth, it won't perturb the level curves away from the minimizer too much, but it's still non-convex.

@WolfgangBangerth I am using mainly Nelder-Mead, but also Spiral Optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_optimization_algorithm, so all gradient-free.  I also use a random "optimizer" as a baseline.

@OscarSmith if I said they seem to make gradually less and less progress as they approach the minimum (eventually "terminating" early) would that give you a useful vision?  Have you tired the function yourself?

@DanielShapero I can eliminate that possibility by mentioning that the solution is not getting as far as the "zero"point, or bracketing it in any sense that I can see (I use an OpenGL visualization for 3D).

Does your iteration get to the ridges at any point? It seems like it should be straightforward to go downhill along a ridge, i.e. using some coordinate-wise gradient descent.

@lightxbulb not an easy one to answer.  In 2D there isn't a problem, and with 3D you don't really get a picture to look at at all, but I suspect that the "valleys" are a big part of the problem.  Certainly at 8D or so you will see several coordinate zeros (now obscured by my "origin shifting"!).

Can you describe in some sort of quantitative way what behavior these solvers are showing?

@whpowell96 I think I am at the limit of what I can describe in words.  If I can find some numerical description I will mention it here, but I think at that point I will have gone a long way to answering my question myself.  I am not there yet!

Even in 100D if you end up in a ridge then there will be a coordinate that is non-zero for the gradient descent. So I expect gradient/subgradient descent to perform fine.

Yes but won't you have to have some procedure to set the gradient w.r.t. the other coordinates to zero on ridges since those partials don't exist?

@lightxbulb well that would be a good data point ;)  Seriously if anyone tries it and finds it is not hard that is useful information too!

I'm not sure what your question is. As several of us have pointed out, the function is neither convex nor differentiable. This is known to make things difficult for algorithms. What else do you want to know?

@whpowell96 If you're in a ridge along one of the coordinates the function is not differentiable along the coordinate of the ridge. But let's assume you don't know that, i.e. the function is a black box. If you take finite differences along said coordinate in the two possible directions it will suggest to not move along it anyways. So once you get to a ridge you can essentially ignore one of the coordinates. In either case, I see no reason gradient descent should not work provided you handle the non-differentiability properly (i.e. you mske the partial derivative along $i$ zero when $x_i = 0$)

I think that if gradient descent got near one of the ridges, the gradients would point almost orthogonal to the ridge direction since that partial is unbounded. You'd basically get stuck line searching forever unless you already knew where the ridges were and manually applied a rule to ignore some partials once you were within some tolerance of them.

It will all depend on how exactly you compute the finite-difference approximation of the gradient.

@WolfgangBangerth Yes, I pointed it out in my OP too, so why "pretend" that I am not aware of this? As I have explained, the algorithms I am testing this on know and care nothing about derivatives, and I don't understand why they should care about convexity either.  I am looking for some kind of "mechanism" behind the slow-down.  Either that, or a "works for me, use a better algorithm!".  OK, here is a question for you: would you expect a random "optimizer" to be adversely affected by these abstract mathematical concepts?

@whpowell96 I don't see how you would get stuck line searching forever - even if your gradient blows up along said coordinate moving along this coordinate would still lead you into the ridge. And that's assuming you take an analytical unregularized gradient. If you take a finite difference that already regulrazies your problem through the step size. If you use coordinatewise stochastic gradient descent then you will altogether ignore the problematic coordinate in a number of steps and still move. And if you treat this as a fixed coord whenever the gradient blows up you are also fine.

@m4r35n357 Yes, I would absolutely expect a derivative-free algorithm to work slower on a non-differentiable objective function than on a differentiable one. That's because generally you compute the error reduction using a Taylor expansion, but you can only take Taylor expansions so far if the function lacks smoothness.

@WolfgangBangerth we may be at cross-purposes here; when I say random optimizer I mean one where you take a sequence of random points and evaluate them, keeping the lowest cost one (as opposed a randomly-selected optimizer!).  Is that how you took it?

Oh, I took it as "choose an optimization algorithm at random". I'm going to try and put my thoughts into an answer where I have more space.

@WolfgangBangerth OK, I thought so ;)  BTW I have added my current thoughts to the OP.

From: H-G Beyer and B. Sendhoff, Simplify Your Covariance Matrix Adaptation Evolution Strategy, IEEE TRANS. ON EVOLUTIONARY COMP, 2017. p.12: It seems that CMAv3.36-ES has been "tuned" for the Sphere and Sharp ridge.
I take the authors to mean that both the evolution path and the evolution of the
covariance matrix in the CMA-ES algorithm are required for good performance
on ridge functions. Their simplified algorithm uses only one evolution path and
dispenses with the covariance matrix. Also see M. Lunacek, D. Whitley, Understanding Self-adaptation on Ridge Functions. PPSN IX, 2006.

Perhaps not quite an answer to the question you are asking, but perhaps still useful:
If you take, for example, the Nelder-Mead simplex algorithm, you might be forgiven to think that because it never asks the objective function for a gradient (i.e., it is "derivative-free"), that the performance of the algorithm should not suffer if the objective function is not differentiable. But that is not true.
Let's for simplicity look at it in 2d. If you think about how the algorithm works, it is clear that if you take a reflection of a point (i.e., you flip the triangle over an edge), then the new point will be a good choice only if the function continues to go downhill in this direction. You know that that direction is a good direction based on the three points you currently have. In essence, reflecting the point with the worst function value across the edge connecting the two points with the better function values will definitely yield a new point with an even better function value if the function is linear, and will likely yield a better point if the function is approximately linear. For smooth functions, Taylor's theorem guarantees that the function is approximately linear if the triangle you currently have is small enough. In essence, what that means is that while the algorithm never actually asks for a gradient, it is still following a gradient direction of some sort.
But imagine a situation where the objective function is not differentiable along a line just past the edge between the two better points. Say that it has a "crease" or "fold", like in your figure. In that case, all assumptions about whether that reflected point will be better than the old one are invalid, and in many cases it may not actually be. What happens in that case is that the algorithm will continue to shrink the triangle until eventually it may make progress again, but it is clear that you shouldn't expect it to converge rapidly.

Thanks, that is an interesting take on things, I'll ponder on this.  As for the OP, what baffles me is that there is an obvious downhill path at all points towards the (known!) minimum, so the reflections should IMO tend to be downhill at all times. That this does not happen (for NM to terminate early it needs to "reflect in" or shrink many times) seems odd on the face of it.

If the fold is near the good edge, then the reflected point on the other side is no better than the original one. The algorithm's choice in that case is to shrink the triangle, but you will soon again be in the same situation.

That sounds right to me - I was grappling for the right words myself.  I suppose we must also conclude that "sliding into the groove" at some point is pretty much inevitable (perhaps even more so in higher dimensions?), in other words the "clear" downhill path is "divergent/unstable".

OK thanks, now I just need to understand why Spiral Optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_optimization_algorithm also struggles, in both "settings" ;)

@m4r35n357 All (good) derivative-free algorithms have the property that they choose a search direction or a new point based on something that, when looked at carefully, is an approximation of the gradient of the objective function computed from the already accumulated knowledge. That's why they're efficient -- you somehow need to come up with a descent direction. But as a consequence, they all also suffer if the objective function is not differentiable.

OK thanks, that is good enough for me!

Having said that (!), I have just implemented this very simple method that I only found a few days ago https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.05953v1.  It is a little similar to the Spiral algorithm, but uses a shrinking box instead, which is populated randomly each iteration.  It is hard (for me) to see how gradients can be brought into this, perhaps you might accept the challenge ;)  Needless to say, it gets "bogged down" in the treacle too.

@m4r35n357 The algorithm shrinks the search domain $\Omega_n$ towards the currently best point (and consequently away from the currently worst points). Your gradient is right there.

Interesting question - just like the previous one.
Your test function is indeed annoying for quite a few solvers, and it appears to me that it might belong to the Schwefel family (see, for example, the Schwefel20 function):

And its 3D representation:

Other Schwefel functions are catalogued in my benchmarks here:
https://infinity77.net/go_2021/scipy_test_functions_nd_S.html
I have run a few optimizers here and there on your (modified) test function, with these specs:

Varying dimensionality (2 to 9)
With random starting points in the interval -512 < x < 512 (the random starting point is the same for all solvers)
Maximum 50,000 functions evaluations

I have tried most of the (global) solvers described in my benchmark page:
https://infinity77.net/go_2021/index.html#algorithms-tested-algorithms
And I get this nice table of objective function value vs. dimensionality vs. minimizers:

Basically, the vast majority of the really robust global solvers got to the global minimum without breaking a sweat. That said, global solvers that rely on gradient-based local minimizers in the minimization phase do take a hit compared to the others (I have set AMPGO and Dual Annealing to use L-BFGS-B as the local minimizer).
Since you seem passionate about optimization, I'd suggest you to throw your optimizers at the "HappyCat" test function:

Often defined like this:

I found that it's a hard one to properly minimize.
Back to your problem, fun would be to test local solvers (gradient-based or gradient-free) with varying dimensionality, and possibly report on the success rate and on the number of functions evaluations used. NLOpt and SciPy are a good starting point, with large collections of local minimizers.

Yes, I found "treacle" after experimenting with simple things like sum(|x_i|).  But the abs() on its own it trivially "easy", the sqrt() is what makes "treacle" sticky ;)  I am engrossed in my "vanity" project(s), so I am happy to do experiments within that environment (including "Happy Cat" - thanks for that!), but not so inclined to set up other environments (e.g. my models are all shared between algorithms that I have coded myself, in c).  Incidentally the only "Schwefel" function I am familiar with is this beast: https://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/schwef.html

Incidentally, I am using equation (3) from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234024034_HappyCat_-_A_Simple_Function_Class_Where_Well-Known_Direct_Search_Algorithms_Do_Fail.  I think your exponent in the first term is off by a factor of two compared with that.  Apologies if I have messed up ;)

There are different formulations of the HappyCat function - in my Python code, the exponent in the first term is actually a variable, i.e., you can make it 1/4, 1/8, whatever you like, to test different behaviors.

Yes, it is variable in that paper, too (which looks like the original), it just looks like your equation above is missing a power of two, or includes it in $\alpha$.  Incidentally, it is starting to look (to me) like the "hard part" in general is fractional powers. I suppose I should be enquiring whether these functions are representative of real-life problems, or just good for testing optimizers ;)
